# Open modal windows or popups from a Hyperlink site column

Tags: modal-dialog, sharepoint-2013, linkfieldvalue

I need to open a modal window or popup from a SharePoint site column, when the user clicks on a link shown by this column.

I have tried to use these types of site columns:

- Full HTML content with formatting and constraints for publishing
- Hyperlink with formatting and constraints for publishing

but I don't know how exactly to use them. What should I put as content? I have tried this code from C# but that does not work:

```
private LinkFieldValue linkField = new LinkFieldValue();     
linkField.NavigateUrl = "javascript:window.open('Pages/delete.aspx?Id='" + id +",width='300',height ='300', toolbar='no')";                                
linkField.Text = "Delete";
linkField.UseDefaultIcon = true;
linkField.ToolTip = "Delete";
```

Comment: So what happens when you click on a link constructed using your code?

Comment: doesn't work, nothing... I think there are some solution but i can't find it...

Comment: Please post *all* relevant code. What do you do with the `linkField` variable then?

Comment: linkfield is the content of the column.

it["Operation"] = linkField;
it.Update();
And when I click on the link nothing is happen..

Comment: Does the link appear correct in the browser?

Comment: No, nothing appear...